Can karate framework be connected to a SQL Server odbc database?
I am trying to connect a SQL Server database via ODBC with the karate framework to make queries and validate the record of certain data.
Do you have any idea how to do it?
I understand that karate uses jdbc without any problem but I am not sure if with an odbc it would be necessary to make some change or some additional steps?

Even the JDBC examples require you to write some Java code (one time activity). This is how you can connect anything to Karate as long as you can find a Java library for it.
Here is an example of connecting AWS DynamoDB: Karate and AWS DynamoDB. It includes an explanation and links to other relevant examples.
Since there exists a JDBC driver for SQL Server, you should be easily able to achieve what you want.
